# Swift swizzling init function

Tags: swift, method-swizzling

I'm trying to capture initialisation of InputStream with file URL in Swift. I've successfully implemented such capture in Objective-C for NSInputStream class.
The issue is that after exchanging initialisers, swizzled method is not triggered. Furthermore, after method exchange, calling swizzled method directly does not lead to its execution, meaning, its implementation was successfully exchanged.  I'd like to know, what are the reasons of such odd behaviour, as method is swizzled successfully, but it's not clear, which method was replaced by swizzled one. Provided sample with current implementation of InputStream swizzling in Swift.

```
private let swizzling: (AnyClass, Selector, Selector) -> () = { forClass, originalSelector, swizzledSelector in
  if let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, originalSelector),
     let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector)  {
      method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
  }
}

extension InputStream {
  @objc dynamic func swizzledInit(url: URL) -> InputStream? {
      print("Swizzled constructor")
      return self.swizzledInit(url: url)
  }
  
  static func Swizzle() {
      swizzling(InputStream.self, #selector(InputStream.init(url:)), #selector(swizzledInit(url:)))
  }
}
```

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/inputstream): "`NSInputStream` is an _abstract superclass_ of a class cluster consisting of concrete subclasses" When you create an `InputStream`, the object you get back _isn't_ of class `InputStream`, it's actually of a different type. In Obj-C, you can see this directly: `+[NSInputStream alloc]` returns to you a private `NSCFInputStream`. So your `init(url:)` is never called because you're swizzling it on the _superclass_.

Comment: Because of this, swizzling a class cluster is especially fragile. Is there something specific you need to be swizzling for, or is this question primarily because you're curious? (If the former, there _may_ be a better solution than swizzling.)

Comment: The former, I'm interested in capturing names of files, which are initialised.

Comment: And, in case of specific files, initialising object with data

Comment: In that case, you can try to swizzle the method on `NSClassFromString("NSCFInputStream")` and see where you get. If that still doesn't work, we can dig a bit deeper.

Comment: (With the explicit understanding that that class is private, its name may change, it may go away, etc. If you need to go through App Store review, it's also possible that doing this may trip things up.)

Comment: Swizzling private class does help: constructor gets triggered as expected. Thanks for help!

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped. I've turned the above comments into a more full-fledged answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`InputStream` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/inputstream):

> `NSInputStream` is an abstract superclass of a *class cluster* consisting of concrete subclasses of `NSStream` that provide standard read-only access to stream data.

The key here: when you create an `InputStream`, the object you get back will not be of type `InputStream`, but a (private) subclass of `InputStream`. Much like the Foundation collection types (`NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`, `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary`, etc.), the parent type you interface with is not the *effective* type you're working on: when you `+alloc` one of these types, the returned object is usually of a private subclass.

In most cases, this is irrelevant implementation detail, but in your case, because you're trying to swizzle an *initializer*, you do actually care about the value returned from `+alloc`, since you're swizzling an initializer which is never getting called.

In the specific case of `InputStream`, the value returned from `+[NSInputStream alloc]` is of the private `NSCFInputStream` class, which is the effective toll-free bridged type shared with CoreFoundation. *This is private implementation detail that **may change at any time***, but you can swizzle the initializer on *that* class instead:

```
guard let class = NSClassFromString("NSCFInputStream") else {
    // Handle the fact that the class is absent / has changed.
    return
}

swizzling(class, #selector(InputStream.init(url:)), #selector(swizzledInit(url:)))
```

Note that if you're submitting an app for App Store Review, it is possible that the inclusion of a private class name may affect the review process.